# Ember Non-Trivial Router With Multiple BelongsTo Relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I'm building a project management app with three main models:

`Client`, `Project`, `Task`

**My models (relationships only)**

```
let client = DS.Model.extend({
  projects: DS.hasMany('project');
});

let project = DS.Model.extend({
  client: DS.belongsTo('client'),
  tasks: DS.hasMany('task')
});

let task = DS.Model.extend({
  project: DS.belongsTo('project')
});
```

**Requirements:**

1. Display list of all clients
2. Display list of all a client's projects (not nested in UI)
3. Display list of a project's tasks (not nested in UI)
4. Display task's details (not nested in UI)
5. Display list of all projects for all clients (yep, not nested)

---

I'm not sure if it's incorrect to reflect model relationships by nesting resources as such:

```
/** Creates a nested UI by default: */
this.route('clients', function() {
  this.route('projects', function() {
    this.route('tasks', function() {});
  });
});
```

I don't want my UI to be nested and show all the projects below all the clients etc.

---

*Is there a better way of handling resources than this?*

```
// All projects for all clients
this.route('projects', function(){});

// Client's projects
this.route('clientProjects', { path: 'client/:id/projects' }, function() {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting routes doesn't necessarily mean that you have to use the nested templates. Each route creates both its route and an index child route. You can see what I mean with this nested list.

```
* clients
    * clients.index
    * clients.projects
        * clients.projects.index
        * clients.projects.tasks
            * clients.projects.tasks.index
```

**Note:** There is also a much more interactive representation of what I'm talking about [at this link](https://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/?routesInput=this.route(%27clients%27%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20this.route(%27projects%27%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.route(%27tasks%27%2C%20function()%20%7B%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D)%3B).

If you look at the tree, you can see that `clients.index` is a sibling to `clients.projects`. Therefore, if the `clients.projects` template is showing, it will have replaced `clients.index`, but still be under `clients`. The same is true for the `clients.projects` -> `clients.projects.tasks` templates.

This distinction allows you to put whatever you want in each template and have it either retained (nested) or replaced (not). You can fully utilize all of these templates to have some parts nested and some parts not.

For example, if you put a menu of clients in the `clients` template, and you put an overview page with statistics about all clients in the `clients.index` template, when you navigate to the clients.projects template, you will still see the menu with all clients, but the overview template will be replaced.

Any templates that you don't explicitly create will be created for you with the default `{{outlet}}` so that they're nestable. Therefore, if you don't create the `clients` template and put everything in the `clients.index` template, it will still work, but everything will get replaced when you navigate to the `clients.projects` template.

---

**Resources**

- [Ember Guide on Routes](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/)
- [Diagonal Routes Graphical UI](https://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/?routesInput=this.route(%27clients%27%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20this.route(%27projects%27%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.route(%27tasks%27%2C%20function()%20%7B%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D)%3B)

**Also of note:** `resource` will be deprecated before 2.0, so it's recommended that you just use `route` everywhere.

---

**Ember-cli Implementation Commands**

```
$ ember new myapp && cd myapp
$ ember g route clients -p
$ ember g template clients/index -p
$ ember g route clients/projects -p
$ ember g template clients/projects/index -p
$ ember g route clients/projects/tasks -p
```

Comment: For those of us less familiar with Ember *magic*, it may be worth mentioning, that if you don't create a specific index templates for clients, projects and tasks you will see that default nested UI behavior to avoid.

Comment: I added some more information about templates -- I think that when you say 'UI behavior to avoid' it makes it sound like it's a bad thing. It's only something that you have decided you don't want. Others may find that behavior desirable.

Comment: Great point Mike!  Really appreciate everything.  There aren't a ton of indexed resources on this point of the Ember learning curve, so your help has been huge.

Comment: You bet!! I think one of the great things about Ember that helps offset its learning curve is that the community is huge and helpful. I'm just glad I was able to help someone else!